# Depth of Huffman nodes

Tags: java

I'm new in Java. I'm trying to obtain the average depth tree depth. I already have the number of nodes. I just need each node's depth. I have a method to obtain the height of the tree. I'm thinking if I could use this method and reverse it to obtain the depth of every node. But I don't know how to specify the node in the method.
Do you guys have any advice for specifying the nodes one by one in the method?
Right now my method take a tree type as parameter
PS: English is not my native language. Sorry for any confusion

```
import java.util.*;

public class HuffmanCode {
    int numberOfNode = 1;
    int height;
    String fullcode = "";
    String realcode = "";

    // input is an array of frequencies, indexed by character code
    public HuffmanTree createTree(int[] charFreqs) {
        PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree> trees = new PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree>();
        // initially, we have a forest of leaves
        // one for each non-empty character
        for (int x = 0; x < charFreqs.length; x++) {
            if (charFreqs[x] > 0)
                trees.offer(new HuffmanLeaf(charFreqs[x], (char) x));
        }
        /*
         * Step 2 in Huffman coding While loop to remove 2 nodes with the
         * highest priority(lowest probability)
         */
        while (trees.size() > 1) {
            // Poll the two nodes with least frequency
            HuffmanTree a = trees.poll();
            HuffmanTree b = trees.poll();

            // put into new node and re-insert into queue
            trees.offer(new HuffmanNode(a, b));
            numberOfNode++;
        }
        return trees.poll();

    }

    public void printResults(HuffmanTree tree, StringBuffer prefix) {
        if (tree instanceof HuffmanLeaf) {
            HuffmanLeaf leaf = (HuffmanLeaf) tree;

            // print out character, frequency, and code for this leaf (which is
            // just the prefix)
            System.out.println(leaf.value + "\t" + leaf.frequency + "\t" + prefix);
            encodedInput(prefix);
            for (int x = 0; x < leaf.frequency; x++) {
                realcode = realcode + prefix;
            }

        } else if (tree instanceof HuffmanNode) {
            HuffmanNode node = (HuffmanNode) tree;
            numberOfNode++;

            // move left
            prefix.append('0');
            printResults(node.left, prefix);
            prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length() - 1);

            // move right
            prefix.append('1');
            printResults(node.right, prefix);
            prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length() - 1);
            height = findHeight(node);

        }

    }

    public void encodedInput(StringBuffer prefix) {
        fullcode = fullcode + " , " + prefix;

    }

    public int findHeight(HuffmanTree tree) {
        if (tree == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (tree instanceof HuffmanLeaf) {
            return 0;
        } else if (tree instanceof HuffmanNode) {
            int left = findHeight(((HuffmanNode) tree).left);
            int right = findHeight(((HuffmanNode) tree).right);

            if (left > right) {
                return left + 1;
            } else {
                return right + 1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1; // does not happen, you might want to raise exception.
        }
    }

    public void printQueue(PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree> pq) {
        while (pq.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(pq.poll());
        }
    }
}
```

Other class I have:

```
class HuffmanNode extends HuffmanTree {
    public HuffmanTree left;
    public HuffmanTree right;

    public HuffmanNode(HuffmanTree left, HuffmanTree right) {
        super(left.frequency + right.frequency); 
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

class HuffmanLeaf extends HuffmanTree {
    public char value; // the character this leaf represents
    public HuffmanLeaf(int frequency, char value) {
        super(frequency);
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class HuffmanTree implements Comparable<HuffmanTree> {
    public int frequency; // the frequency of this tree

    public HuffmanTree(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }
    public int compareTo(HuffmanTree tree) {
        return frequency - tree.frequency;
    }
}
```

Comment: To get the average height, you need to add up all the leaf node heights and divide it by the number of leaves. You've already got code that calculates the heights of a leaf, you just need to add them up instead of returning the highest one.

Comment: I code right now give me the height of the root. I need to specify every nodes individually. Any advice?

Comment: @Kavi can you calculate of node height when is added to tree ? I think if each node have height to can get avg by traveling tree.

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe help you. you can traverse from root and calculate sum of depth.

```
public int sum(HuffmanTree tree,int currentDepth) {
    if (tree == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (tree instanceof HuffmanLeaf) {
        return currentDepth;
    } else if (tree instanceof HuffmanNode) {
        int left = sum(((HuffmanNode) tree).left , currentDepth+1);
        int right = sum(((HuffmanNode) tree).right, currentDepth+1);
        return left+right;
    } else {
        return -1; // does not happen, you might want to raise exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it take my height as currentDepth?

Comment: @Kavi no. sum(HuffmanTree tree , 0 ) return sum of depth tree. you must divided in to number of node to get avg.